# Using the id of subject{create()} in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm pretty new to rspec so I'm not sure how to word this properly so I'll give an example of my situation instead:

```
subject(:test) { SomeModel.create(name: name, depend: depend) }
let(:name){ "test name" }
let(:depend){ create(:depend, //something here with id of creation of SomeModel) }
```

Depend belongs to SomeModel and so I need the id of SomeModel to create Depend. Is there some way of retrieving the id of the SomeModel I created in the first line? Sorry if this is very unclear as I'm not too sure how to word it.

Comment: `subject.id` or `test.id`

Comment: How this question got two upvotes? Flagged for mod’s attention on who’s upvoted.

Comment: @mudasobwa: if there was a voting ring, this user's rep would have been higher :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev not necessarily, it might be a slave asking dumb questions that yield the attention because of upvotes.

Comment: @mudasobwa sorry if it seemed like too dumb of a question -- turns out I was doing the right thing but because I was still getting an error I thought I was doing something wrong when trying to reference the subject. Turns out something else is wrong with my factories, thanks anyway for the help :)